# Inserting image to temporary file

Tags: php, image, file-upload, temporary-files

I have done my coding that inserting images to temporary file. I am able to upload images with size below 5mb but some of images unable to be inserted and I wonder why. Can somebody tell me what I done wrong in my coding below?

```
$imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
$tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
$imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];

$upload_dir = 'user_images/'; // upload directory

$imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

// valid image extensions
$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

// rename uploading image
$userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

// allow valid image file formats
if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){           
    // Check file size '5MB'
    if($imgSize < 5000000)              {
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
    }
    else{
        $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    }
}
else{
    $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";        
}
```

**EDIT**

I found out that images which size `> 2MB` unable to be moved to the temporary file but it pass the line `if($imgSize < 5000000)`. How do I fix this?

Comment: are you getting any errors? whats your `php.ini` configuration??

Comment: @Jadeye I'm not getting any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is caused by the setting in `php.ini` where `upload_max_filesize` set to `2M`. I hope this will be useful to others that facing the same problem as mine. Go to your `php.ini` and see the **File Uploads** section and find the line `upload_max_filesize = 2M` . Change the `2M` to any size that meeting with your requirement and restart all the services :)